# How to handle below schema, my requirement is split queries and then integrate queries to database related code? how can i do?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, xcode6

I m getting this string from server, then i have to split these queries then and implement to local DB code, so how can i do (handle this string like, split and converting)

> sql://query=CREATE%20TABLE%20employee%20(empid%20INT%2C%20empname%20TEXT%2C%20age%20INT%2C%20gender%20TEXT%2C%20sync%20INT)&sync=1&syncquery=select%20*%20from%20employee%20where%20sync%3E0%20limit%2010&onadded=update%20employee%20set%20sync%3D0%20where%20empid%3D%27%25empid%25%27&onmodified=update%20employee%20set%20sync%3D0%20where%20empid%3D%27%25empid%25%27&ondeleted=delete%20from%20employee%20where%20empid%3D%27%25empid%25%27&syncfrequency=300"];

here i done decoding process,by using below code

```
NSString *decodedText = [query stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Original text: %@", decodedText);`
```

but i want to split all queries by using keys(query, sync,sync query....), how can i do

please help me

Comment: sql query to json??? please review your question title ;)

Comment: and also make the body more understandable ;)

Comment: Please sanitize your code. Please give us example how you imagine sql representation in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s","query=CREATE%20TABLE%20employee%20(empid%20INT%2C%20empname%20TEXT%2C%20age%20INT%2C%20gender%20TEXT%2C%20sync%20INT)&sync=1&syncquery=select%20*%20from%20employee%20where%20sync%3E0%20limit%2010&onadded=update%20employee%20set%20sync%3D0%20where%20empid%3D%27%25empid%25%27&onmodified=update%20employee%20set%20sync%3D0%20where%20empid%3D%27%25empid%25%27&ondeleted=delete%20from%20employee%20where%20empid%3D%27%25empid%25%27&syncfrequency=300"];

NSString *decodedText = [query stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *firstSplit = [decodedText componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

for(NSString *currentString in firstSplit) {

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setValue:[[currentString componentsSeparatedByString:@"query="] lastObject] forKey:@"query"];
    [dict setValue:[[currentString componentsSeparatedByString:@"sync="] lastObject] forKey:@"sync"];
    [dict setValue:[[currentString componentsSeparatedByString:@"syncquery="] lastObject]forKey:@"syncquery"];
    [dict setValue:[[currentString componentsSeparatedByString:@"onadded="] lastObject] forKey:@"onadded"];
    [dict setValue:[[currentString componentsSeparatedByString:@"ondeleted="] lastObject] forKey:@"ondeleted"];
    [dict setValue:[[currentString componentsSeparatedByString:@"syncfrequency="] lastObject] forKey:@"syncfrequency"];

    NSLog(@"%@",dict);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string represents a query, not an entity. It would have no sense converting it to JSON (unless you want to build a parser SQL-to-JSON in a NO-SQL fashion)..

What do you need to do with the query itself? Directly executing it on a local DB or print it to user?